# What if Goku Black is killed before forcefully pulled back by the Space/Time Distortion?

Tags: dragon-ball-super

During the early episodes of Future Trunks Saga, we remember that Trunk's Time Machine created a distortion in space/time which gave an opportunity for Goku Black to follow Trunks to the past using the Ring of Time but in a limited time.
After a few minutes of fighting with Son Goku, we have seen that Goku Black was being pulled by the distortion because it fixes itself. I wonder if Son Goku kills Goku Black before the distortion fixes, would he be brought back to life?

Comment: Why would he be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The answer to this would be yes and no!**

If Goku destroyed black when he followed Future Trunks, He wouldn't have been brought back to life. However, since Future Zamasu in future trunks timeline has a time ring, He could use it to go back to Goku's timeline and possibly replicated what he did before, so in theory Goku black would still be alive but it wouldn't be the same Goku Black.

- When goku and Vegeta wen't to Future trunks's timeline and fought black, when Goku was injured and came back to the timeline, he wasn't automatically alright. So in other words, if goku had tied or had been destroyed by Black, he wouldn't have come back to his actual timeline.
- When future trunks was killed by super perfect cell in the main timeline, they needed to use the dragon balls(of that timeline), to bring him back to life. Also future trunks uses the time machine to go back to his time line and only one of him exists. So in other words, an alternate of him wasn't created in that timeline.
- Also, we know all the Kaioshin's have time rings, and it's something which is only owned by them. Future zamasu had killed all the Kaioshin's and had access to these time rings so irrespective of whether black was destroyed along with his time ring, he'd still be able to go to another time line.
- We also know that when future trunks destroyed the super dragon balls in trunks's universe, it didn't affect the super dragon balls in the mian time line as the prize for the best warrior in the tournament of power, is the super dragon balls